# How to jump to certain position of scrolled element without scrolling the main screen?

Tags: javascript, html, url, scroll

I have a container (`div`) on the page. This container has a scrolling (provided by `overflow:auto; height:400px`).
I need no provide a URL, that will open a page so that the main page will not be scrolled, but the text in the container will  be scrolled.
I tried `www.mysite.com#position`, but by this way the main page is scrolled too (and I need, that users will see the header on the top of the screen, and the "`#position`" position on the top of the container)

Comment: You can make the header fixed. that would be the most easy way.

Comment: Thanks... But it is not a solution for me. I have some other elements besides the header (sidebar and more), that I will have to make `fixed` bu this way, and it's not suitable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with javascript. And I will show a jQuery example here.

```
if (window.location.hash == '#position') {
    $('#containerDiv').animate({
     scrollTop: $("#actual_position").offset().top
 }, 2000);
}
```

The `actual_position` should be the place where to scroll to. `position` should just be in the url and not on the page, to prevent the whole page from scrolling.

Comment: pathname won't  retrieve the anchor, my bad. I will update my answer.

Comment: I try it, but I have a problem: it scrolls the container so that the `#actual_position` is on the top of the main screen, that means - it is in invisible area of the container.  (window.location.hash == '#position' is great, thank you)

Comment: You could play around a bit with the offset until you get it right. `scrollTop: ($("#actual_position").offset().top - 10)` or `scrollTop: $("#actual_position").offset().top + 10`. Just keep changing the numbers till you are where you want to be.

Comment: offset() calculate the position relative to the document. And we need the position relative to container. I will try to do it, and will post here.

Answer (score 0):

May you use the css-properties: position:fixed, top:..., left:... for your element that should stay at a certain place on your side, when an user scrolls. 
Furthermore you can put all content that you do not want to be scrolled into a div and define the css-properties.

I hope this helps you a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Really it's an upgrading of [Arjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887533/arjan) answer (and now this really works).
As Arjan's suggestion the script will not work every time, but only by providing `#scroll` in the end of url (`www.mysite.com#scroll`). This script will scroll the container scroll bar to the `#position` element, and the all document will stay.

```
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
    container_top = jQuery('#container').offset().top;
    element_top = jQuery('#position').offset().top;
    element_relative_top = element_top -container_top;

    if (window.location.hash == '#scroll') {
        jQuery('#container').animate({
            scrollTop: element_relative_top
        }, 2000);
    }
})
```